# Parse.Cloud.play can't find function

Tags: javascript, android, parse-platform, push-notification, httprequest

I think I am misunderstanding something in the .play() function. I've spent days trying to figure this out.

I have a Define setup for a function in main.js.

```
var pvp_module = require('cloud/otherCode.js');
function pushBattleMessage_sum(request, response)
{
    pvp_module.PushNotification_BattleMessageExport(request, response);
}

Parse.Cloud.define("PushNotification_BattleMessage", pushBattleMessage_sum);
```

This sends it to another otherCode.js that runs the code. Inside that code I need to call a second Cloud function.

```
function PushNotification_BattleMessage(request, response)
{

    Parse.Cloud.run("push_httpRequest",{request},
    {
        sucess: function(results) 
        {
          response.success(results);
        },
        error: function(error) 
        {
          response.error(error);
        }
    });
}
```

The second cloud function is defined back in main.js

```
Parse.Cloud.define('push_httpRequest',function(request)
{
  Parse.Cloud.httpRequest(
  {
    url: 'http://www.parse.com/',
    success: function(httpResponse) 
    {
      console.log(httpResponse.text);
    },
    error: function(httpResponse) 
    {
      console.error('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status);
    }
  });
});
```

Everything that I have found online tells me that this should be working but in my testharness html I always receive the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: push_httpRequest is not defined"

The purpose of this code is that Android requirements state that the push notification icon must be in black and white. I cannot initialize that change with server-side parse so we are feeding our push notification for GCM devices through httpRequest. I should be able to pull all of that together if I can get my first Cloud function to find the second one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see in the documentation, the `define` method of `Parse.Cloud` object requires a function which should take two parameters. Your function `push_httpRequest` then is not correctly defined. From [Parse documentation](https://www.parse.com/docs/js/api/classes/Parse.Cloud.html#methods_define):

> `define( name, func )`
>
> Defines a Cloud Function.
>
> Available in Cloud Code only. Parameters:
>
> - name `<String>`
>     The name of the Cloud Function
> - func `<Function>`
>     The Cloud Function to register. This function should take two parameters a `Parse.Cloud.FunctionRequest` and `Parse.Cloud.FunctionResponse`